# nested forms and nested_attributes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Suppose I have 3 models `A B C`, with

```
class A
  has_many :Bs, through: :Cs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :Cs
end

class B
  has_many :As, through: :Cs
end

class C
  belongs_to :A
  belongs_to :B
end
```

and in my view I have some nested forms

```
= form_for @A do |f|
...
  = f.fields_for :Cs do |builder|
  ...
```

but I get an error

```
ArgumentError (No association found for name `C'. Has it been defined yet?)
```

What did I do bad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add :

```
    class A
      has_many :Cs
      has_many :Bs, through: :Cs
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :Cs
    end

    class B
      has_many :Cs
      has_many :As, through: :Cs
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a `has_many :Cs` missing on `class A`.